# Docker: "Cannot assign requested address while connecting to upstream"

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have docker running on a machine with the IP address fd42:1337::31. One container is a nginx reverse proxy with the port mapping 443:443, in its configuration file it *proxy_pass*-es depending on the server name to other ports on the same machine, e.g.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name plex.mydomain.tld;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://[fd42:1337::31]:32400;
    }


}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name file.mydomain.tld;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://[fd42:1337::31]:2020;
    }


}
```

These other ports refer to bottle py servers or other containers with mapped ports.

I've started this container with the command

```
docker run -d -p 443:443 (volume mappings) --name reverseproxy nginx
```

and it has served me well for a year.

I've now decided to work with docker-compose and have the following configuration file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    reverseproxy:
        image: "nginx"
        ports:
        - "443:443"
        volumes:
        (volume mappings)
```

When I shut down the original container and start my new one with *docker-compose up*, it starts, but every request gives me something like this:

```
2019/02/13 17:04:43 [crit] 6#6: *1 connect() to [fd42:1337::31]:32400 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.178.126, server: plex.mydomain.tld, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[fd42:1337::31]:32400/", host: "plex.mydomain.tld"
```

**Why is the new container behaving differently? What do I have to change?**

(I know I can have a virtual network mode to connect to other containers directly, but my proxy is supposed to connect to some services that are not inside containers (but on the same metal).)